# Analytical model fitting

Tags: fitting

I have a special type of model fitting problem that I am trying to solve in Mathematica. Any insight how to attack it using available tools of Mathematica will be great to hear.

We have a variable
$$
H=\{h_k\}, \text{ where } k=1,...,15,
$$
and each $h_k$ is a 4-tuple of complex numbers
$$
    h_k=\{a_j+i b_j\} \text{ where } j=1,...,4 
$$
and $a_j,b_j$ are normally distributed real numbers.

Now this $H$ is mapped to a object $P=\{p,c\}$ where $p$ is a permutation of **integers** $\{2,3,...,16\}$ and $c$ is a **real** number. Now we seek to find an analytic model $f$ such that $f:H \rightarrow P$. Through a Monte Carlo simulation I have got 50000 data for this map $f$. I am stuck with the question about what kind of analytical model to choose and which fitting procedure will be best if one wants to solve this problem in Mathematica?
Hope to hear from you people.

Comment: Welcome, PlatoManiac. [LaTeX formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/117/2283) is enabled on this site. Also, there are some [conventions](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135/52) in place from the private beta which you may want to review. Good luck.

Comment: I think will get better answers if you explain a little more about the problem.  Are you seeking an analytical form that you can fit to this?  Hoe do you arrive from a matrix of complex numbers to a permutation?  (Is it the ordering of another set of 15 real numbers?)  What does $c$ mean?

Comment: Think about it like this:  If you asked "I have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what kind of analytical model can I fit it to?", it would still seem very vague and much too general.  Can you be more specific?  What answer would *you* give to my example question?

Comment: @Szablocs The problem is I don't have much more information either. I just have got the data. I only know that after a sequence of computation on each $H$ gives an output that consists of $p$ which is a permutation of the integers $\{2,3,..,16\}$ and a real number $c$ between 0 to 100. So I cant say $f$ as an analytical model should have this and that properties. I was wandering if the probabilistic/statistical information about the complex numbers can give us any extra insight when we choose a model. Do you think LinearModelFit or NonLinearModelFit is a possible point to start with.

Comment: I also don't have any effective way to visualize my data set. Any suggestion will be great to know.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Both of those functions are for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ transformations only, and require a hypothetical transformation function with parameters.  All they do is try to find good parameters (with which the model approximates the data well).

Comment: Also, are you looking to find an analytical model that reproduces your data, or perhaps any "black box device" that can reproduce it by whatever means will do?  In the latter case you could ask some machine learning or neural network experts (I have next to zero knowledge of those fields)

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually speaking I get this data from a black-box. Now I am looking for a analytic model to match that black-box behavior. So my situation better suits the first possibility you mentioned of. I personally find this problem pretty ill  defined but given this scenario what will be best way to tackle it in MMA. I can attach some data example in case someone is interested to give it a try.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Ideally, 1. you come up with an idea for $f$ (call it $f^*$) which has parameters $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...$, and implement a function that calculates it  2. You define a distance function on $P$  3. you minimize the distance function wrt $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...$ so $f^*$ will give a result as close as possible to the data.  But you probably know this.  I think this is not really a Mathematica question, but a method-question.

Comment: DataModeler from http://evolved-analytics.com/ is intended for this sort of problem. It is a commercial product built on Mathematica. They have a 60-day trial version and also an academic license option. (I realize this constitutes an advertisement, but the fact is that the product is intended for specifically this type of problem.)

Comment: Or perhaps something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/6117644/615464?

Comment: What @DanielLichtblau said is a good point. They socialize on derivation of models driven by data, when you have not much to go on at the start. Looks like your case. You can contact them through their website and they will probably clarify if their solution is appropriate for you.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you have a 120 dimension input space. Imagine sampling the real number line with just 2 points. To keep the same sampling density as that you would need 2^120 input samples.Currently you have 50000^(1/120) points per dimension. Unless your input space is highly non- uniform you may well find you are very undersampled.

Comment: @I am aware of that and my input space is highly non-uniform indeed.

Comment: If it is very non-uniform with strongly defined clusters you might have some progress using a Radial Basis function approach. In effect you could try something like dropping a multi-dimensional gaussian on each of the clusters.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I'm curious if you've identified a solution to this problem outside of M.SE that would be worthy of an answer?

Comment: @bobthechemist Nope! I could not find anything as such.